# How to on full stack PHP project with team in sync

Tags: php, mysql, git, server

It's our first time to work as a team. We are 4 of us trying to build a project using PHP MySQL AJAX HTML CSS JS n Bootstrap.

If I were alone I'll just install xampp and run the code on localhost and code in my vscode till it's done and when I'm satisfied I host it, but now we are a team of 4 and have to work on different parts of the project, so we thought we use git to handle version control. But the issue is each of us will have to install and run xampp and import the SQL file each time on our local machines before working.

Is there a better way to go through this smoothly ?

So I made some research and I learned about CI CD and staging servers.

But I don't know if this will really solve the issue.

Please if you understand my issue help me with a good and simple solution

Comment: Your suggested approach sounds basically fine. If you are each working on different features in different branches you shouldn't interfere with each other too much. You can then merge and deploy to a central server for integration testing. SQL changes are a bit trickier, but if you write clear change scripts that others can apply to their copies when needed, it should be ok. If you need to make schema changes for feature X which is likely to have an impact on other areas of the system, then you need to have a discussion as a team about how/when/where to apply it.

Comment: you don't need synced datas for local dev environment. You might want the same DB design, tho. You can use a dev server hosted and available to each devs if you want a common environment

Comment: P.S. You can read a lot about git development workflows and branching strategies online already I would expect - lots of people blog about their ways of working. Take inspiration from those. I would be surprised if we need to write another essay about it here.

Comment: Generally each developer would set up their own local environment. In your case that would mean each person sets up xampp, etc. You may want to consider a database migration tool like flyway to manage database versioning across local feature branches and your server environment(s). I agree with @ADyson that this is such a common pattern that there is likely a plethora of write ups online of different ways to achieve this.

Comment: I would highly suggest to use docker-compose for the dev environment because its easier to setup for each person. For database you can use fixtures to generate test data or just include the sql file in the repository. You could also import it when building the mysql container in your docker compose config.